# SQL case when - create new variable

Tags: sql

**QUESTION:
Is it possible to write a SQL statement where I create a new variable 'ART2' that solves:
if holdid <> stamholdid then Art = Art where holdid = stamholdid
I guess it is some form of 'case when'-statement

I have the following SQL:**

```
select ua.betegnelse as ART, ut.betegnelse as TYPE, rh.stamholdnr, rh.holdnr, rh.stamholdid, rh.holdid,
rh.produkt
from rpthold rh 
INNER JOIN produkt p on p.id=rh.produktid
INNER JOIN UddannelseType ut on p.UddannelsesTypeID=ut.id
INNER JOIN UddannelseArt ua on ut.UddannelseArtID=ua.id

Where 
rh.stamprodukt like '3.58'
and rh.stamholdnr like '21.06%'
and Year(rh.startdato) = '2021'
```

*Best regards
Malene*

Answer (score 0):

You have "case when" with if functions:

```sql
SELECT
  IF (
    <some_condition>,
    CASE
      WHEN <CONDITION>
        THEN <value>
      WHEN <OTHER_CONDITION>
        THEN <other_value>
    END,
    <default_value>  
  ) as name_field
FROM...
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `CASE..WHEN` as follows:

```
case when rh.stamholdid = rh.holdid then 'Art - or whatever value you need'
     else 'value you want if both are not equal'
end as art2
```